# How might I get a notification of Realm collection deletion?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

If I have a collection of Realm objects in my class:

```
var sessions: Results<Session>? {
    return realm?.objects(Session.self)
}
```

How might I go about getting a notification when an object is deleted? I have used the collection `addNotificationBlock` function elsewhere, but this only returns an index of the deleted object.

In my case I have a parent view controller, with two child view controllers; one is a calendar (`UICollectionView`), one is a table view of `Session` objects for that date.

If a user deletes a `Session`, I wish to **always** refresh the calendar date for the session date, and **only** refresh the table view if we are currently displaying that date.

Is my only option to blindly call reload data on both the collection view and table view whenever the collection changes?

Comment: I think that `addNotificationBlock()` achieves what you want. What's the problem? Can you explain more details?

Comment: `addNotificationBlock()` returns an index of the changed object. However, the deleted object is already gone, so I can't fetch it. In my instance I want to know the date of the deleted session to know if I need to refresh any views. I've worked around it by changing my implementation, but there must be a cleaner way.

Comment: I see. In Realm, there is no way to access deleted objects. I think the better way is using soft delete. For example, add `deletedAt` property, then treat it as deleted if the property is present.

Comment: Yes, while that would work, I think its fairly inelegant. Instead what I ended up doing was forwarding the instruction to delete up to the parent view controller, which then performed the actual delete, and refreshed the calendar view.